# Как получить количество просмотров поста вк python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, views

Всем привет! Столкнулся с трудностью в подсчете количества просмотров у поста вк python [image: количество просмотров на сайте] Число формата 3.4к я получить могу, а вот точное количество просмотров(3428) я не могу, на вход получаю только ссылку vk.com/wall-{owner_id}_{id}.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможно, могут помочь поля **reach_subscribers** и **reach_total** из [документации](https://dev.vk.com/method/stats.getPostReach)

Comment: Решил вопрос с помощью wall.getById